# Why getting requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool error while using TFSAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, tfs, python-requests, httpconnection

I was working on establishing connection with TFS using dohq-tfs library.

But when I am trying to extract the workitem using `get_workitem()`, it is throwing the **requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool** error.

I used https://devopshq.github.io for reference.

Comment: Can you share all your code?

Comment: I used the same coding as given in https://devopshq.github.io as I am new to it. But it's throwing error.